# Problem on Universal link with mail app and gmail app

Tags: ios, swift, email, branch.io

I've configured a universal via `branch.io`. 
My link seems to be working when presented as `https://example.com` in a **mail** or **gmail**.

However, this doesn't look good and people don't tend to click on plain old links. We're using hypertext reference tags and Button tags to make it bit friendly.
It looks something like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com"> Go to App </a>
```

Problem now we've is that this **`Go to App` link/button** doesn't work in native mail or gmail app. Instead of taking us to our app, mail app tries to open `this link <a href>` in safari. It then takes us to our app's App Store page.
Peculiar thing is If I open gmail in safari to start with and open the link from there then safari seems to understand that this is universal link and it segues into my app.

In summary:

1.**Safari** can open any link including **hypertext reference**  or **button tag**

2.Both **Mail** and **gmail app** don't support  **hypertext reference**  nor **button tag** but plain old link `https://example.com` is fine in both the app

Has anybody gone through similar situation ? Appreciate any sort of help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of limitation when you hyperlink a universal link. I would recommend you to use Branch Universal email which allows you a seamless email to app integration. Please see:

https://branch.io/universal-email/
https://docs.branch.io/emails/universal-email

In case you still have any other doubt, reach out to support@branch.io

Comment: We are in constant contact with branch.io. Right now, the link require some link of c-name linking. With SendGrid email our link of `https://example.com` is being redirected to `http:u12345678.ct.sengrid.net` which is unrecognizable by our app